# How to run a Fortran program within GNU Octave?

Tags: fortran, octave

I want to run a Fortran program within Octave. I would like to do this for automation purposes and use Octave for all the data processing.

Is it possible to run a Fortran program from octave using cygwin, if so, could you provide me some pointers along that direction?

Moreover, I have a gfortran compiler installed in my system, Is there a way I could make use of it to complete my task mentioned above?

Furthermore, I tried to use mex to perform the same:

```
mckoctfile --mex HelloWorld.f
```

I got the following error after trying the mex approach:

```
c:/octave/octave~1.0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\rajan\AppData\Local\Temp/oct-qur1RF.o: in function `hi': C:\Tech Stuff\Fortran Programs/HelloWorld.f:3: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
c:/octave/octave~1.0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Tech Stuff\Fortran Programs/HelloWorld.f:3: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
c:/octave/octave~1.0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Tech Stuff\Fortran Programs/HelloWorld.f:3: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
c:/octave/octave~1.0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\rajan\AppData\Local\Temp/oct-qur1RF.o: in function `main':C:\Tech Stuff\Fortran Programs/HelloWorld.f:6: undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_args'
c:/octave/octave~1.0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Tech Stuff\Fortran Programs/HelloWorld.f:6: undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_options'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
warning: mkoctfile: building exited with failure sta
```

How do I resolve this error to move forward?

Comment: it's not something I have much experience in, but, out of curiosity, it didn't sound like compatibility with matlab was much of a concern; why go for mexfiles and not the more natively supported octfiles interface?

Comment: your error messages sound more like not linking to the right fortran libraries, and less like something to do with octave. E.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794543/unable-to-compile-f-fortran-file-in-codeblocks-13-12). Note that mkoctfile is essentially a wrapper to the gnu compiler, which loads a bunch of octave-related libraries for convenience under the hood, but you can still pass the usual options and arguments that you'd normally pass to the gnu compiler.

Comment: I am doing this for the first time. Hence, I looked up the wen and proceeded with the mexfiles. How do I then use the octfiles instead ? Any pointer in that direction would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: The best place to start would be the online manual; [here](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/External-Code-Interface.html#External-Code-Interface) is the section on external-code-interfaces (including fortran).

Comment: I checked it out but could not understand anything.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your particular use-case may be a lot more complex than this, but here's a simple example to get you started (or to help you decide whether it's worth going down that route at all...)

Let's start with a simple octfile which performs simple integer addition, no fortran involved for now.

```
// in: simple_addition.cpp 
#include <octave/oct.h>

DEFUN_DLD (simple_addition, args, ,"Add two integers via C++")
{
  octave_value retval = args(0).int_value() + args(1).int_value();
  return retval;
}
```

Compile:

```
mkoctfile -c simple_addition.cpp                 # compiles a simple_addition.o file
mkoctfile -o simple_addition simple_addition.o   # links .o file to named output file
```

In octave:

```
octave:1> simple_addition(1,2)
ans =  3
```

Now let's put this aside for a minute, and see how we might call a fortran-defined function from pure c++. First let's create a simple integer addition function:

```
 ! in fortran_addition.f90 
 function fortran_addition(a,b) result(Out)
    integer, intent(in) :: a,b ! input
    integer             :: Out ! output
    Out = a + b
 end function fortran_addition
```

and compile it using gfortran:

```
gfortran -c fortran_addition.f90    # creates fortran_addition.o
```

You can see (e.g. using `nm fortran_addition.o`) that the generated object contains a reference to a symbol under the name `fortran_addition_` (note the added underscore at the end).

Now let's create a normal (i.e. non-octave-related) c++ wrapper program which calls the function defined via this symbol:

```
// in generic_fortran_addition_wrapper.cpp
#include <iostream>
extern "C" { int fortran_addition_( int *, int * ); }
int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2, fortran_result;
    fortran_result = fortran_addition_( &a, &b );
    std::cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << fortran_result << std::endl;
}
```

compile:

```
g++ -c generic_fortran_addition_wrapper.cpp
g++ -o addints generic_fortran_addition_wrapper.o fortran_addition.o
./addints   # outputs `1 + 2 = 3` on the terminal
```

Now we have all the ingredients to create an octfile that wraps a fortran function:

```
// in fortran_addition_wrapper.cpp
#include <octave/oct.h>
extern "C" { int fortran_addition_( int *, int *); }
DEFUN_DLD (fortran_addition_wrapper, args, ,"Add two integers via fortran")
{
  int a, b, fortran_result;
  a = args(0).int_value();
  b = args(1).int_value();
  fortran_result = fortran_addition_( &a, &b );
  octave_value retval(fortran_result);
  return retval;
}
```

compile with mkoctfile:

```
mkoctfile -c fortran_addition_wrapper.cpp
mkoctfile -o fortran_addition_wrapper fortran_addition_wrapper.o fortran_addition.o
```

and then in octave:

```
octave:1> fortran_addition_wrapper(1,2)
ans =  3
```

---

Having said all this, obviously if you have a fully defined fortran program, rather than just linkable functions, and you have a running compiled executable on your system, then you can skip all the above 'formalities' and just call your executable via the `system()` command from octave. Obviously in this scenario it's up to you to pass the data in an octave-agnostic way ... but presumably if you have a standalone fortran executable, then presumably it already has a way of reading input data from the operating system.

**EDIT** as per the comments below, I've been reminded that I got side-tracked and answered the question that was asked in the comments to the original question, and forgot to address the error messages in the original question. As mentioned in my comment there, mkoctave is a generic wrapper to the gnu compiler collection. Those messages do not sound specific to octave, but rather that the compiler/linker complains that you're missing the fortran runtime libraries that define these basic functions.

Comment: Does creating a C++ function which calls a Fortran function ensure that the gfortran RTL is linked against without further effort on the user's part?  If it does, are there any hints in that process how the user can directly link a Fortran function without having to go to the effort of creating additional C++ parts?

Comment: @francescalus I don't pretend to be an expert, but I would assume that any .o machine-code object file generated by a gnu compiler can be straightforwardly linked to an executable as long as the linker is happy that the right symbols exist for linkage. Having said that, here I inspected (with `nm`) the generated object to see what symbol name was given to the fortran function; I am aware there are formal "binding" instructions to use straight in the fortran code to generate more predictable symbol names, but here I worked on the assumption that the user would not want to touch the fortran code

Comment: @francescalus as for the "octave-compatible" c++ generated file specifically, I am not aware of a pure-fortran interface for generating those. The octave-developers have only provided these macros for C++ as far as I'm aware.

Comment: The error in the question relates to symbols in the gfortran RTL not being found by the linker. It seems odd to me that it'd be necessary to add a C++ layer to allow the linking against a Fortran RTL, or that using C++ removes the gfortran dependency.

Comment: @francescalus oh, of course! You're right! I got side-tracked! I'll update accordingly